# Is Raul Silva's prosthesis a computer?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, skyfall

Risk seems null when Raul Silva is isolated in a glass cage:

[image: Raul Silva in glass cage]

But Silva nevertheless manages to break into the MI6 computer system at that moment. How?

1. His prosthesis hides a tongue-controlled computer that connects wirelessly to his laptop
2. He had programmed everything in advance (sounds impossible: MI6 just moved, so infrastructure has probably still changed a lot since his arrest)
3. He is helped by his team (improbable: The movie seem to imply that only Q and Silva are hackers)
4. Other?

Comment: Looks like not, but it's a really cool idea.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In fact it wasn't Silva who hacked into the MI6 system but Q, when he plugged in the hard drive they obtained from Silva. Silva planned all this in advance. When causing an explosion right inside the MI6 headquarters, he forced them to move to this old bunker (since he knew their security protocols). And he also knew they would try to access the hard drive, so he made the password easy enough to guess.

This is also explained in the movie, when Silva escaped and they realize that all of this (including his capture, of course) was planned out perfectly by him.

Comment: Plugging notorious hackers' laptop into your main net... typical IT expert approach.

Answer (score 4):

After the breakout, Bond realises Silva had planned everything in advance. He knew that MI6 would retreat to the tunnels after the bombing. He then planted his computer virus that takes over Q's framework while Q tries to hack Silva's code. This is further supported by the fact that Q acknowledges that Silva is a master hacker. Silva had the tools to program an attack on MI6 without him having to push any extra buttons.

Option 1 seems unlikely as no real indication of it is seen in the movie.

Answer (score 0):

It is option 2

The physical infrastructure had changed but the way computers work had not.  They still had the same systems, they either had backups, brought the physical machines across, or accessed them in the cloud.  Either way Silva had deep knowledge of MI6, it's procedures and it's capababilities.

Also, he was a spy and master hacker so he almost definitely had accessed and read all kinds of things when he was at MI6 that he was not supposed to.  Look how Bond hacks M's password etc.  Imagine how much more a master hacker could do with the computer networks, no information would be safe!

Answer (score 0):

Other. This virus implanted by the laptop

The secure floor panels started popping up and Q said, "Why are those opening?" We were supposed to figure out, like Bond, that it also meant Silva's cell door was opening. Apparently since Silva knew it was going to happen it gave him the edge to use his mad skills and take out two armed guards.